# How do I enable Libreoffice Base 7.5 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, openjdk

I've added openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18:

- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

About LibreOffice shows:

```
Version: 7.5.3.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 50(Build:2)
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 5.19; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Ubuntu package version: 4:7.5.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1
Calc: threaded
```

The Base option is faded and I haven't found anything to enable Base.

Comment: have you tried to install it from Ubuntu Software?

Comment: How did you install Libreoffice?

Comment: LibreOffice was installed as part of Ubuntu 22.04 approximately 11/2022.  After running the OpenJDK install, I updated to LibreOffice 7.5 following suggested terminal command from "FOSS*"/?  I just now ran the test for a corrupted profile and got:  'Warning: failed to launch javaldx - java may not function correctly'   However, I'm still clueless!!   Thanks for looking and trying.

Comment: I just ran the "FOSS" instruction again.  Then I ran the profile test again.  BASE is now available and working and I have no idea why.

Comment: And now it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

After running the Ubuntu Software install, BASE is available and working.